# Using a Java pattern Globally PatternCaptureGroupTokenFilter

Tags: java, regex, elasticsearch, lucene, regex-lookarounds

I am currently using the Pattern Capture Group Token Filter inside an Elasticsearch plugin. Currently, the plugin is working absolutely fine and is emitting the tokens also. But, the issue is that the pattern which I am using inside the Pattern Capture Group Token Filter, it is returning only the first match and not continuing the matching after it.

My Pattern Capture Token Filter definition inside the TokenFilterFactory file looks like the below one:

```
PatternCaptureGroupTokenFilter(tokenStream, true, Pattern.compile("(?<![\\p{Alnum}])(\\p{Alnum}+\\p{Punct}\\p{Alnum}+)"))
```

I know in the case of JAVA, I can solve this issue by using find() and group() methods, but don't know if it can be resolved simply with the pattern itself.

The pattern that I want to test is "(?<![\p{Alnum}])(\p{Alnum}+\p{Punct}\p{Alnum}+)".I want to test it on the string: ":port&hid$query-input" And, I am expecting the following tokens as output. port&hid, hid$query, query-input

My code in the java file looks like:

```
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenStream;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.pattern.PatternCaptureGroupTokenFilter;
import org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings;
import org.elasticsearch.env.Environment;
import org.elasticsearch.index.IndexSettings;
import org.elasticsearch.index.analysis.AbstractTokenFilterFactory;

import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class AlPuAlTokenFilterFactory extends AbstractTokenFilterFactory {

    public AlPuAlTokenFilterFactory(IndexSettings indexSettings, Environment environment, String name, Settings settings) {
        super(indexSettings, name, settings);

    }

    @Override
    public TokenStream create(TokenStream tokenStream) {
        return new PatternCaptureGroupTokenFilter(tokenStream, true, Pattern.compile("(\\p{Alnum}+\\p{Punct}\\p{Alnum}+)(?=(\\p{Punct}))"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide sample input and output as example

Comment: @RizwanM.Tuman The pattern that I want to test is "(?<![\\p{Alnum}])(\\p{Alnum}+\\p{Punct}\\p{Alnum}+)".I want to test it on the string: ":port&hid$query-input" And, I am expecting the following tokens as output. port&hid, hid$query, query-input

Answer (score 1):

You may try this:

```
(\w+[&$-])(?=(\w+))
```

Explanation:

1. Here I get a word `\w+` followed by & or $ or -. I package this as Group 1
2. Then I positively look ahead for another immediate word. I package this as group 2.

So you get your desired ouput from group 1 and group 2 from 3 matches:

```
Match1: port&
group 1:port&
group 2:hid

Match 2: hid$
group 1:hid$
group 2:query

Match 3:query-
group 1:query-
group 2:input
```

So you get your desired ouput from group 1 and group 2

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GrwhFj/1)

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Is there a way by which I can combine the matches from both groups. Actually, my usecase requires both to be a single token.

Comment: Well I need to see your java code snippet to understand the use case, please add that into your original question.

Comment: Hi, Rizwan! I have just updated my question with my java code. Actually, I am creating an elasticsearch token filter.